# C# - TestStack White Error: Failed to get ControlType=text, AutomationID = _autoID

Tags: c#, white-framework

I used the inspect application to get the automation ID of a label with a control type, text, but when I run the code, it does not work. What could be the problem? others worked just fine.

I can't use the ByText Search criteria because the label's text changes, and my task is to retrieve the value of that label.

```
TestStack.White.UIItems.Label _Status = 
        winView.Window.Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.Label>
                           (SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("_autoID"));
```

Comment: Are you attempting to automate a wpf application? Also can you post a screen shot of inspect so I can take a look at the properties on the label you are attempting to get?

Comment: If this is possible, you can try to find parent element and then find elements in this parent (example parent: UIA_PaneControlTypeId or other containers)

Answer (score -3):

1. Create the Main project
2. Add the Test project in it
3. Then perform operation

Note:(Add test project to the Main project ,then there will be no error in finding automation Id)